# How to access resources in Java Struts 1 app

Tags: image, struts, itext

In a Struts 1 Web App I can access images from a .jsp by

```
<img src="../../images/myImageName.png"/>
```

Am I also able to reference that image from a .java class in my source directory?

I am using iText and can fetch an image from a url

```
    String imageUrl = "http://jenkov.com/images/" +
                       "20081123-20081123-3E1W7902-small-portrait.jpg";

    Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
```

but if I try and fetch one from

```
    Image image = Image.getInstance("../../images/myImageName.png"/);
```

It always looks in the bin folder of my server. How can I get the `relativePath` back to my image?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in the web app *content* directory then you need the app context relative path:

```
String relativeWebPath = "images/myImageName.png";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
```

Would I do that? Not unless there's a good reason; I'd prefer either a path off the app context altogether (and the image could be streamed by the app, or set as a symlink, etc) or a classpath-based resource.